# return column name from QSqlQuery

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to create a small program which should display a tableview based on sqlite table where dates are stored. When a validity is passed the cell shows red to indicate the validity has expired. I have a method "get_date_diff" which retrieves the emails and dates expired and stores them in lists to later use those as variable for mails to be sent in batch i.e: Email(var) has the certificate (var) expired on date (var). My `if` statement gets me the expired dates and the emails in the `listes_pilotes` and `mail_pilotes` i need the third list to be filled with the culprit certificate : was it in column certificate1, certificate2 or possibly both:

```
def get_date_diff(self):
    '''method to retrieve from DB expired certificates '''
    query = QSqlQuery("SELECT pilot_1,certificate1,certificate2,pilot_mail FROM Pilots")
    liste_pilotes = []
    mail_pilotes = []
    #certificate_expired = [] needs to be filled
    append_new = liste_pilotes.append
    append_new_mail = mail_pilotes.append
    while query_time.next():
        pilot_1 = query.value(0)
        date1 = query.value(1)
        date2 = query.value(2)
        pilot_mail = query.value(3)
        alter_certif1 = datetime.strptime(date1,"%Y-%m-%d")
        alter_certif2 = datetime.strptime(date2,"%Y-%m-%d")
        if alter_date1  < datetime.now() or alter_date2 < datetime.now():
            append_new(pilot_1)
            append_new_mail(pilot_mail)
    return liste_pilotes,mail_pilotes
```

[image: SAMPLE OF THE TABLE]

the DB on which the tableview is based:

```
from PyQt5.QtSql import *

class LmtDataBase():
    def __init__(self):
        self.db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
        self.db.setDatabaseName("LmtPilots.db")

        self.db.open()

        query = QSqlQuery()
        query.exec_('''CREATE TABLE Pilots(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,pilot_1 TEXT, datetime1 TEXT, datetime2 TEXT,pilot_mail TEXT)''')

        self.db.commit()
        self.db.close()

        # ...
```

Comment: Could you explain me better, what does the title of your question have to do with the content of it? Also, you do not explain it clearly, maybe with some sample data, if you are using sqlite it would be advisable that you share the .db, if you are using Another database may share a .sql that can generate a test data.

Comment: Hi  @eyllanesc, I have added a picture of the intended program.As you can see in this example smith has certifi1 and 2 expired, williams only certif2 and klein certif1. The function( method really) returns the name and and the email off that table in the list to later use it. The problem: I do i get to know if red came from column 1 i.e certif1 or column2 i.e certif2?

Comment: In the visual example that shows, what should the output of get_date_diff be? Could you share the .db?

Comment: I point it out to you because what output if both certificates are expired, or if only one or only the second ?, I understand that for the last cases it is enough to indicate 2 or 3, but in the case of both?

Comment: This is only a draft code eventually I'll have probably 12 columns with 12 certificates to check. So it will be for example certif 6,9 and 10 for one guy, the other will have maybe only 1 or maybe all ....

Comment: Okay, so you want every row that has at least one expired certificate to sign out the expired certificate columns, am I correct?

Comment: Apart from the above, I would like you to show me what type of field do the certified columns have?

Comment: some feedback??

Comment: Exactly.@eyllanesc

Comment: Okay, now for example according to what you show the output should be: `[(1, "xxx@yyyy", [2, 3]), (3, "xxx@yyyy", [3]), (4, "xxx@yyyy", [2])]`. I am right?

Comment: with the above table this is what i get if I do a print:`(['SMITH', 'WILLIAMS', 'KLEIN'], ['smith@xxxl.com', 'williams@xxx.com', 'azerty@essai.com'])`

Comment: I do not ask what you get but what you want to obtain, what is the desired output with the table that shows?

Comment: yep, the output should be the one you showed previously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to get the dates and compare by storing them in a list, and if that list has at least one item save the other data:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtSql
import random
import string

def createConnection():
    db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
    db.setDatabaseName(':memory:')
    if not db.open():
        return False

    query = QtSql.QSqlQuery()
    query.exec_('''CREATE TABLE Pilots(
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
        pilot_1 TEXT, 
        certificate1 TEXT, 
        certificate2 TEXT,
        certificate3 TEXT,
        pilot_mail TEXT
        )''')

    for i in range(100):
        query.prepare("insert into Pilots values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")
        query.addBindValue(i)
        query.addBindValue("".join(random.sample(string.ascii_letters, 15)))
        for j in range(3):
            days = random.randint(-10*365, 10*365)
            query.addBindValue(QtCore.QDate.currentDate().addDays(days))
        query.addBindValue("".join(random.sample(string.ascii_letters, 4) + ["@mail.com"]))
        if not query.exec_():
            print("error: ", query.lastError().text())
    return True

class DateDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super(DateDelegate, self).initStyleOption(option, index)
        t = QtCore.QDate.fromString(index.data(), "yyyy-MM-dd")
        if t < QtCore.QDate.currentDate():
            option.backgroundBrush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor("red"))



class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        tableview = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        self.setCentralWidget(tableview)
        query = QtSql.QSqlQuery()
        query.exec_('''SELECT pilot_1, certificate1, certificate2, pilot_mail FROM Pilots''')
        model = QtSql.QSqlQueryModel(self)
        model.setQuery(query)
        tableview.setModel(model)
        for name in ('certificate1', 'certificate2'):
            ix = query.record().indexOf(name)
            delegate = DateDelegate(tableview)
            tableview.setItemDelegateForColumn(ix, delegate)
        print(self.get_date_diff())

    def get_date_diff(self):
        query = QtSql.QSqlQuery("SELECT pilot_1, certificate1, certificate2, pilot_mail FROM Pilots")
        rec = query.record()
        cols = [rec.indexOf(name) for name in  ("certificate1", "certificate2")]
        results = []
        while query.next():
            pilot_1 = query.value(rec.indexOf("pilot_1"))
            pilot_mail = query.value(rec.indexOf("pilot_mail"))
            dates = [QtCore.QDate.fromString(query.value(col), "yyyy-MM-dd") for col in cols]
            filter_columns = [col for col, date in zip(cols, dates) if date < QtCore.QDate.currentDate()]
            if filter_columns:
                v = [pilot_1, pilot_mail, filter_columns]
                results.append(v)
        return results

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    if not createConnection():
        sys.exit(-1)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, brilliant code. Thanks @eyllanesc!